# How to know when to make your "u" in u-substitution something raised to a power?

Tags: calculus, integration

For example, how would I know to make my $u$ the $\sqrt{1-x}$ when given a problem such as to evaluate the integral of $x^2\sqrt{1-x}$?  Is there a logical thinking you use to know $u = \sqrt{1-x}$ rather than just $1-x$?  I just learned $u$-substitution the other day, but my teacher stressed that in nearly all cases we will not have a u raised to a power.

Any info on this would be grateful!

Comment: Thanks Joe Johnson 126 for editing my functions in Latex.

Comment: You can also use $u=1-x$.  Then $du=-dx$ and $x^2=(1-u)^2$.  This leads to the integral $$\int -(1-u)^2\sqrt{u}\,du$$.  Expand the $(1-u)^2$ and distribute the $\sqrt{u}$.  Use power rule.

Comment: Radicals are always tough to deal with; thus, one tries to find a substitution that gets rid of them. In particular, if we look at the factor $u=\sqrt{1-x}$, we can try inverting this relation to yield $x=1-u^2$, $\mathrm dx=-2u \mathrm du$, which is in fact a perfectly working substitution...

Comment: @user24641: No problem.  I love to TeX.

Comment: I somewhat prefer $1-x=u^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$u=\sqrt{1-x}$ is an example of a "rationalizing substitution".  "Rationalizing" means getting rid of the radical.  One writes $u^2=1-x$, so $2u\;du = -dx$.  Then $x$ is replaced by $1-u^2$.  The point is that putting the problem in a form where there are no other functions besides polynomials enables one to rely on the fact that one knows how to deal with polynomials.